# Read a file line per line and store every line read in a single list

Tags: ocaml

I'm a student and I've been given a exercice i've been struggling with for about a month or so.
I'm trying to write a function in Ocaml. This function must read a text file which has a word per line, and it must store all the words in a list.
But the problem is that this program must be a recursive one (which means no loops, no "while").

All I've been able to do so far is to create a function which reads the text file (pretty much like the BASH command "cat")

```
let dico filename =
  let f = open_in filename in
  let rec dico_rec () =
    try
      print_string (input_line f);
      print_newline ();
      dico_rec();
    with End_of_file -> close_in f
  in dico_rec() ;;
```

I just don't know how to do it. Ocaml is hardly my favourite language.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate definition of `build_list` that is tail recursive. You can use it instead of @MitchellGouzenko's definition if your inputs can have many lines.

```
let rec build_list l =
    match input_line ic with
    | line -> build_list (line :: l)
    | exception End_of_file -> close_in ic; List.rev l
```

Comment: what does that function do ?

Comment: actually the file i'm using is about 500-600 lines long, so i don't think there would be a stack overflow at some point

Comment: This is the best answer I've found.  I don't understand why all the other answers that I find in an internet search use try-with in these complicated ways, when a simple match works so well.

Answer (score 0):

```
open Printf

let file = "example.dat"

let () =
     let ic = open_in file in
     let rec build_list infile =
          try
               let line = input_line infile in
               line :: build_list(infile)
          with End_of_file ->
               close_in infile;
               [] in
     let rec print_list = function
          [] -> ()
          | e::l -> print_string e ; print_string " " ; print_list l in
     print_list(build_list(ic))
```

Edit: The algorithm I previously proposed was unnecessarily complicated. Try to understand this one instead.

To understand this recursion, we assume that build_list works correctly. That is, assume build_list correctly takes an open file as an argument and returns a list of lines in the file.

Now, let's look at the function's body. It reads a line from the file and calls build_list again. If there are N lines in the file, calling build_list again should return a list of the remaining N-1 lines in the file (since we just read the first line ourselves). We append the line we just read to the list returned from build_list, and return the resulting list, which has all N lines.

The recursion continues until it hits the base case. The base case is when there's an End_of_file. In this case we return an empty list.

Comment: This will work for small input files, but this definition of `build_list` is not tail recursive and will cause a stack overflow for large inputs. The `try...with` surrounding the recursive call prevents its being a tail call.

Comment: Good call... been a while since I used ocaml :) Do you think that the new `build_list` is better, or the old one (which involved passing an empty list as an argument)? Assuming of course that I fix the `try...with` bit.

Comment: I  blush to admit this to OP, who's apparently not an OCaml fan, but you do have to learn to recognize tail calls when writing OCaml code. `try...with` is one of the trickier cases.

Comment: Can somebody explain to me what the "build_list" function is expected to do ? I don't know but I've tried to write it and it returns a "Syntax error" because of the expression "exception"